# add all records from one array to each record from a different array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays where all the information from one array needs to be added to each record from a different array. for example

```
arrUsers ["Cesar", "John"]
```

and

```
arrTrainin ["SOP1", "SOP2","SOP3","SOP4"]
```

the expected result would be

```
arrSOPrecord [
    {"User":"Cesar", "SOP":"SOP1"},
    {"User":"Cesar", "SOP":"SOP2"},
    {"User":"Cesar", "SOP":"SOP3"},
    {"User":"Cesar", "SOP":"SOP4"},
    {"User":"John", "SOP":"SOP1"},
    {"User":"John", "SOP":"SOP2"},
    {"User":"John", "SOP":"SOP3"},
    {"User":"John", "SOP":"SOP4"}
]
```

i have tried just adding the `key.value` to the variable/s but the results are only for one user and SOP combination. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make a single SOP property with an array of [1,2,3,4] as value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you probably want to do:

```
const arrUsers = ['Cesar', 'John'];
const arrTrainin = ['SOP1', 'SOP2', 'SOP3', 'SOP4'];
const arrSOPrecord = [];
arrUsers.map(user => {
    arrTrainin.map(training => {
        arrSOPrecord.push({ User: user, SOP: training });
    });
});
```

Comment: why are you using map?

Comment: why are you using forEach?

Comment: because i do not need a new array from map.

Comment: very pedantic and irrelevant reason, in this case

Comment: This works as expected for the requirements outlined

Comment: Probably should note that this uses ES2016 arrow `=>` functions.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a good idea to use `map` purely for side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the `arrUsers` and the `arrTraining`.

```js
var arrUsers = ["Cesar", "John"],
    arrTraining = ["SOP1", "SOP2", "SOP3", "SOP4"],
    arrSOPrecord = [];

arrUsers.forEach(function (u) {
    arrTraining.forEach(function (t) {
        arrSOPrecord.push({ User: u, SOP: t });
    });
});

console.log(arrSOPrecord);
```